# Dynamic navbar for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm doing a mobile App with jQuery mobile 1.4.3. I'm trying to build a navigation bar that  changes dynamically, If the user has logged in the navigation bar will show 4 options, if not it will show 3 options. The problems:

1. Once I click the bar some times it turns all blue.
2. I'm sure I'm not using the correct code.
3. The navigation bar disappears for some time when I click in a button.
4. The blue click highlight is not persistent for the page click.

What I need is a fixed navigation bar that smoothly changes pages when clicked :)

http://jsfiddle.net/claire89/toxtcbhe/14/

```
var statusLogin = null;
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (e, ui) {
    var myNavbar = null;
    if (statusLogin == null) {

        myNavbar = $('<div data-role="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed"><div data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="#listMenuPage" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-theme="a">Menu</a></li><li><a href="#sugestionsPage" data-icon="grid" class="ui-state-persist" data-theme="a">Sugestions</a></li><li><a href="#historyPage" data-icon="grid" class="ui-state-persist" data-theme="a">History</a></li><li><a href="#settingsPage" data-icon="grid" class="ui-state-persist" data-theme="a">Settings</a></li></ul></div></div>');
        $('.ui-content').append(myNavbar).trigger('create');
    } else {
        myNavbar = $('<div data-role="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed"><div data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="#listMenuPage" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-theme="a">Menu</a></li><li><a href="#historyPage" data-icon="grid" class="ui-state-persist" data-theme="a">History</a></li><li><a href="#settingsPage" data-icon="grid" class="ui-state-persist" data-theme="a">Settings</a></li></ul></div></div>').appendTo('.ui-content');
        $('.content').append(myNavbar).trigger('create');
    }

    $("[data-role='navbar']").navbar();
    $("[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']").toolbar();

    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    var activePageId = activePage[0].id;
    switch (activePageId) {
        case 'listMenuPage':
            alert("listMenuPage");
            break;
        case 'sugestionsPage':
            alert("sugestionsPage");
            break;
        case 'settingsPage':
            alert("settingsPage");
            break;
        case 'historyPage':
            alert("historyPage");
            break;
        default:
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*footer* div should be a direct child of *page* div, you should not place it inside *content* div. Moreover, you need to `.remove()` *footer* or *navbar* once you leave a page before you inject a new one. Otherwise, you will end up adding duplicating both *footer* and *navbar* in same page whenever the same page is shown.

Another note, when you inject *toolbar* dynamically, you need to reset the height of active page `$.mobile.resetActivePageHeight()` as *toolbars* adds padding to page, if height isn't reset, the page will scroll.

For better results, use `pagecontainerbeforeshow` to inject *footer* and *navbar*, and `pagecontainerhide` to remove them.

```
var statusLogin = null;

$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (e, ui) {
   /* ui.toPage was introduced in 1.4.3 
    * can be used instead of "getActivePage"
    * on pagecontainer events
    */
   var activePage = $(ui.toPage),
       activePageId = activePage[0].id,
       myNavbar = "";

   if (statusLogin == null) {
       myNavbar = $('<tags></tags>');
       activePage.append(myNavbar);

   } else {

       myNavbar = $('<tags></tags>');
       activePage.append(myNavbar);
   }

   /* create footer and navbar
    * add active class to button based on page's ID
    */
    $("[data-role='footer']")
        .toolbar()
        .find("a[href=#" + activePageId + "]")
        .addClass("ui-btn-active");
   /* reset height of active page */
   $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight();

}).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, ui) {
   /* remove footer once page is hidden */
   $(".ui-footer", ui.prevPage).remove();
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kLvdf057/)**